# @throw not caught by @catch block?

Tags: objective-c, try-catch, nsexception

If there is a code which looks like

```
@try
{
    @throw [NSException new];
}
@catch (NSException ex)
{
    NSLog(@"exception caught");
}
```

in this case, the code does not go to @catch block, rather the application crashes. How should we catch exceptions throws by @throw in objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[NSException new]` instantiates a `null` class because it contains no useful information. It **does not** generate an `NSException` instance, and as such your:

```
@catch (NSException *ex)
{
    NSLog(@"exception caught");
}
```

is useless. However, if you use:

```
@catch (id exception)
{

}
```

You will catch this empty object.

An excerpt from the official documentation on [Handling Exceptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000059-SW1):

> You can have a sequence of @catch error-handling blocks. Each block
>   handles an exception object of a different type. You should order this
>   sequence of @catch blocks from the most-specific to the least-specific
>   type of exception object (the least specific type being id) ...

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) For everyone else, here is the link that discusses the same in more detail: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000059-SW1

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to initialize the NSException using the

`@throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Exception!" reason:nil userInfo:nil];`

or some other valid way to construct NSException listed in the "Creating and Raising an NSException Object" page in Apple documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSException